# XML Parsing using DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to parse a xml into a map of key-value pairs as follows.

Sample xml document:

```
<Students>
    <StudentA>
        <Id>123</Id>
        <Address>123 W </Address>
        <Courses>
            <Course1>CS203</Course1>
            <Course2>CS206</Course2>
        </Courses>
    </StudentA>
    <StudentB>
        <Id>124</Id>
        <Address>124 W </Address>
        <Courses>
            <Course1>CS202</Course1>
            <Course2>CS204</Course2>
        </Courses>
    </StudentB>
</Students>
```

The xml parser code:

```
/**
 * Parse the given xml data.
 * @param xmlString The xml string to be parsed.
 * @return Non-null list of {@link DiscreteDataEntry} values, may be empty.
 */
Map<String, String> parseXML(final String xmlString)
{
    final String xmlDataToParse = xmlString;

    parentNode = "";
    try
    {
        final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlDataToParse.getBytes());
        final DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        final Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        final Map<String, String> data = createMapOfAttributeValuesKeyedByName(document.getDocumentElement());
    }
    catch (final Exception exception)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception:" + exception);
    }

    return data;
}

/**
 * A recursive method which will loop through all the xml nodes.
 * @param node The node.
 * @return Non-null map of test values keyed by test name, may be empty.
 */
Map<String, String> createMapOfAttributeValuesKeyedByName(final Node node)
{
    final Map<String, String> attributeValuesKeyedByName = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    final NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++)
    {
        final Node currentNode = nodeList.item(index);
        if (node.getFirstChild() != null && node.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            parentNode = getAncestralOrigin(currentNode);
            attributeValuesKeyedByName.putAll(createMapOfAttributeValuesKeyedByName(currentNode));
        }
        else if (node.getFirstChild() != null && node.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
        {
            final String attributeName = parentNode.length() > 0 ? parentNode + "." + node.getNodeName().trim() : node.getNodeName().trim();
            final String attributeValue = node.getTextContent().trim();
            attributeValuesKeyedByName.put(attributeName, attributeValue);
            parentNode = "";
        }
    }

    return attributeValuesKeyedByName;
}

/**
 * Parses a give node and finds all its ancestors.
 * @param node The node whose ancestors have to be found.
 * @return A non-null but possible empty string built using the ancestors of the node.
 */
final String getAncestralOrigin(final Node node)
{
    String ancestralOrigin = "";
    final Node currentParentNode = node.getParentNode();
    if (currentParentNode != null && currentParentNode.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE)
    {
        ancestralOrigin = currentParentNode.getNodeName();
        final String ancestor = getAncestralOrigin(currentParentNode);
        if (ancestor.length() > 0)
        {
            ancestralOrigin = ancestor + "." + ancestralOrigin;
        }
    }
    return ancestralOrigin;
}
```

The output of the map is :

```
Key:[Students.StudentA.Id], Value:[123]
Key:[Students.StudentA.Address], Value:[123 W]
Key:[Students.StudentA.Courses.Course1], Value:[CS203]
Key:[Students.StudentA.Courses.Course2], Value:[CS206]
Key:[Students.StudentB.Id], Value:[124]
Key:[Students.StudentB.Address], Value:[124 W]
Key:[Students.StudentB.Courses.Course1], Value:[CS202]
Key:[Students.StudentB.Courses.Course2], Value:[CS204]
```

But this output works fine if the file is being read with

```
final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new     File(url.getFile().replaceAll("%20", " "))));
```

if the same file is read with

```
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(url.getFile().replaceAll("%20", " "))));
```

the output is different. It does take all CR and LF within the xml doc.

Key:[Students], Value:[123
        123 W

```
        CS203
        CS206



    124
    124 W 

        CS202
        CS204]
```

I am using a dependency jar to read xml file which uses DataInputStream.

I was always under the impression that my xml parsers would take care of CR/LF/NewLine looks like its not.
I am replacing all CR LF and NewLines with empty string before parsing it.

But I would like to know if there are other xml parsers which would take care of itself. Also what is the reason behind BufferedReader skipping CR/LF and NewLine
but where as DataInputStream would not.

Also Is there any other better way to find the ancestors of the child tag, I need them to make the key value unique.

The xml will be as it is and cannot be changed. Also the xml will not be same as being shown here, it will be a generic xml with tags
changing, so I am trying to make a generic xml parser that parses xml child tags and puts them into a map.

The child tags can be duplicated so, I am using the path to the child to make it unique.

Also is there a way to parse the xml with just these tags(StudentA/StudentB) recursively by removing parent tag Students.

Note: The xml format changes and xml that I parse might be changing for every xml file.
So I really can't parse like get children of StudentA.

Comment: This example source might be a good start: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/ In the cases where the format changes, you could check for empty nodes and just have it return a 0.

Comment: I can tell you that vtd-xml definitely takes care of the CR/LF for you.

Answer (score 0):

After go through long description, I learn that, you want to know other better way to parse XML.

The answer is, **Yes**, there are some other better way to parse XML. Use `StAX` or `SAX`, these are fast and more memory efficient. To learn more read `JAXP` of Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

`DataInputStream` is intended to read only something written using a `DataOutputStream`... i.e. serialized Java objects.  It is not intended for reading text input.